# Servlet dependency error after add browsermob-proxy lib

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, browsermob

After adding browsermob-proxy to the `pom.xml`, when I was trying to start the webapp, it threw an exception:

[image: Screenshot]

D**: the exception log

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1191)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

Comment: Please write the log text in your post, the image is impractical for reading the text

Comment: @dvhh  already add some log info